# extracting and index of dates and times, with varying opening and closing times for minutely ohlc data in R

Tags: r, indexing, time-series, xts

I would like to be able to get an index of dates and times that represent the opening and closing times of a financial stock-market index for each day.

However the opening and closing times vary due to changes in the rules from an exchange or due to daylight savings, therefore I would to be able to use this index to accurately get Open to Close returns.

I am currently look at the Hang Seng futures index which also has a lunch-break in the middle so I would like this to noted as well in the index. I.E. I would have two opening to closing returns per day due to this lunch-break gap in the data. The time that the lunch break is not always consistent so using the xts function of xts["THH:MM/THH:MM"], would not work. In subsetting the timeseries to be able to get Open to Close data for a specific day

For example the lunch-break times changed in 2011 in March, so when comparing the 14th Feb 2011 lunch break vs the 14th March 2011 lunch break you have the following data...

```
> HI.raw.sing['20110214']["T12:25/T14:35"]
                    HI.Open HI.High HI.Low HI.Close HI.Volume
2011-02-14 12:25:00   23020   23028  23018    23018       180
2011-02-14 12:26:00   23018   23023  23014    23019       108
2011-02-14 12:27:00   23020   23033  23016    23033       142
2011-02-14 12:28:00   23031   23038  23025    23026       173
2011-02-14 12:29:00   23026   23046  23026    23042       264
2011-02-14 12:30:00   23044   23059  23041    23042       314
2011-02-14 14:30:00   23044   23044  23044    23044       311
2011-02-14 14:31:00   23118   23129  23099    23117       781
2011-02-14 14:32:00   23117   23143  23113    23143       554
2011-02-14 14:33:00   23143   23156  23139    23139       762
2011-02-14 14:34:00   23139   23161  23138    23138       644
2011-02-14 14:35:00   23139   23149  23137    23144       326
Warning message:
timezone of object (Asia/Singapore) is different than current timezone (). 

> HI.raw.sing['20110314']["T11:55/T13:35"]
                    HI.Open HI.High HI.Low HI.Close HI.Volume
2011-03-14 11:55:00   23060   23075  23059    23071       195
2011-03-14 11:56:00   23071   23071  23059    23064       187
2011-03-14 11:57:00   23064   23074  23063    23068        96
2011-03-14 11:58:00   23069   23075  23068    23075       116
2011-03-14 11:59:00   23075   23078  23069    23073       120
2011-03-14 12:00:00   23073   23098  23073    23089       231
2011-03-14 13:30:00   23090   23090  23090    23090       103
2011-03-14 13:31:00   23082   23112  23074    23108       326
2011-03-14 13:32:00   23108   23124  23100    23123       179
2011-03-14 13:33:00   23124   23133  23111    23111       326
2011-03-14 13:34:00   23110   23119  23103    23115       148
2011-03-14 13:35:00   23115   23139  23114    23129       284
Warning message:
timezone of object (Asia/Singapore) is different than current timezone ().
```

Notice how the lunch break started at 12:30 on the 14th Feb 2011 but started at 12:00 on the 14th March.

Basically what I am looking for is an ability to detect these breaks in the timestamps. However using missing consecutive timestamp does not always work as there are sometimes missing minutes where nothing traded during the middle of the trading day, and so it is missed when the data was recorded. What I'm looking for is, gaps in the timeseries xts data greater than 5 minutes, output as a list which can be manipulated or be used as an index, which could help me subset the data easily.

Comment: The HangSeng lunchtime has changed a few times, but _only_ a few (the above change you note was 2011-03-07, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Stock_Exchange#Trading_hours) So the way I handled doing something similar to you was to simply describe all those expected gaps. I then have code very similar to Vincent's answer for discovering any other gap (my purpose was to discover missing data, as a data validation step).

Comment: Yeh, I agree that the hang seng trading hours have not changed very much, however this is part of a much wider program to look at generic market data and I felt that this change was something that illustrated my point quite nicely, and thus a solution to this issue would be a solution to my wider issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff(index(x))` to identify holes exceeding 5 minutes.

```
# Sample data
k <- 100
library(xts)
x <- xts( rnorm(100), sort(Sys.time() + runif(100, 0, 5*3600)) )
# Start of the breaks exceeding 5 minutes
i <- diff(index(x)) > 300
close <- x[c(which(i),length(x))]
open  <- x[c(1,which(i)+1)]
break_start <- index(close)
break_end   <- index(open)
```